# I there a way to remove a URL from browser back button history?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All requests in my website are implemented using Ajax. So pages never refresh. I change the URL like this:

```
window.history.pushState("object", "title", path);
```

Also I have made my own customized both back a forward buttons. Now I need to also manipulate the links that are placed in the browser both back and forward buttons. I mean when you execute `window.history.pushState("object", "title", path);`, then the previous url is getting placed as the first item of the browser back button stack. Now I need to remove that item from the browser back button stack using JS. Is is possible?

Comment: Are you just after [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method)?

Comment: Will executing `history.replaceState()` *(without passing argument)* pop the first item of the browser back button history? right? @Phil

Comment: I'm honestly not sure (never used it myself) but it sounds like instead of using `pushState`, you want to use `replaceState` to replace the current state, thus eliminating it from the stack. Again, I'm not entirely certain that's how it works or if that's what you want but it's worth a try :)

Comment: I came across same situation. did `replaceState()` work for you? @MartinAJ